# Creating Local AMP Application on Network Share

Tags: php, mysql, apache, networking

I've recently begun to develope web applications with Apache web server, MySQL database server and PHP.  My work is looking for a cheap efficient way to update an older split Access database which currently is configured with the backend residing on a network share and the front-end being distributed to end users.

Is it possible to install an AMP stack on a network drive and have multiple users at different locations access a php site on an Apache web server backed by a MySQL server. Could the end users simply access the site through the IP address of the network drive?

Any feedback is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: This question would be better suited for ServerFault.

Comment: Apache is by definition an HTTP server. You would not want to install it on a network drive. There are tools that you could use to access your Access database from a network drive but a far better solution would be to import the data from Access to mysql.

Comment: That was my plan Cfreak. I was going to import the Access database into a mysql and create a simple php site to act as the front-end to access the data.  The idea would be to have the site be hosted locally since only a handful of end-users need to use it.  Im just not sure of how I would set up the infastructure to have this be a efficient application.  Thank you for your feedback Cfreak and simshaun.

Comment: @JMan - well yes you can host it locally. People access it like any other website (just by IP or if you have an internal domain setup)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you can install it on a network drive because apache server needs to run as a service and binds its self with port 80 or any other as you customise.

All I can suggest is you can install wamp http://www.wampserver.com/en/ on any of your network machines and access it locally from within your network.

Simple as it sounds.